# Why does a system assume ground state at absolute zero temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, equilibrium, ground-state

I am going through Huang, Statistical Mechanics. He says at 0 kelvin, a quantum system assumes ground state so that $S=k_B ln(G)$ holds where $G$ is the degeneracy of the ground state .

My question is:
Why does a system assume ground state at absolute zero temperature?
I tried to answer through $ d S/ dE = \infty$ and $ S= k_B ln \omega$ where $\omega$ is the density of states at energy $E$, but gets me nowhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of being in a state of energy $E$ is proportional to $\exp(-E/kT)$ where $k$ is Boltzmann’s constant and $T$ is the absolute temperature. So when $T=0$, higher-energy states are infinitely less probable than the ground state.